# How to get a ball to bounce randomly in Corona sdk lua

Tags: android, iphone, coronasdk

I found out how to bounce a balloon around the screen, but when I add another object, they both go in the same direction. I want the balloons to move randomly around the screen with directions of their own. Here's the code:

```
 group = self.view
 point = {x=100,y=100}
 speed = {x=10,y=10}
 dimensions = {0,0,320,480}
```

I declare my vars.

```
function positionBall(thePoint)
--   print("ball is at" .. thePoint.x .. " , ".. thePoint.y)
   balloon01.x = point.x
   balloon01.y = point.y
   balloon02.x = point.x
   balloon02.y = point.y
end
```

Referring to my image which is *balloon 01* and *balloon 02*

```
function moveBall()
--print"i like to move it"
  local newX, newY = point.x + speed.x, point.y + speed.y
  if newX > dimensions[3] or newX < dimensions[1] then speed.x = - speed.x end if newY > dimensions[4] or 
  newY < dimensions[2] then speed.y = - speed.y end
  point.x = point.x + speed.x
  point.y = point.y + speed.y
end
```

Moving the ball. I am wondering if I should use math.random API but I am not sure where to put it.

```
function loop_it_all(event)
    positionBall(point)
    moveBall()
end
```

Looping my functions to be called every frame:

```
Runtime:addEventListener ( "enterFrame", loop_it_all )
```

Can someone please help me? I would love to get this right.

Thanks a million :)

Comment: In the positionBall method you set the x and y of both balls to the same value.  What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: i want the ball to bounce in a random position

Comment: i try to change the positions don't work ;/

Comment: can someone please help me make this ball float and bounce around in a random position